# Для одного класса разные стили scss

Tags: css, scss

У меня есть класс `.modal`, который определяет размеры модального окна. Этот класс используется везде, где можно открыть модальное окно, он является основным. Под каждое модальное окно нужны разные высота и ширина. Внутри класса `.modal` используются уникальные классы, по типу `.modal > .store-modal`, `.modal > .options-modal`... Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы класс `.modal` имел зависимость от внутреннего класса... если класс `.store-modal`, то использовать эту ширину и высоту, если класс `.options-modal`, то другую... Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Что вам мешает размеры `.modal` сделать по размеру содержимого, а уже содержимому назначать размеры, используя ваши селекторы `.modal > .store-modal`, `.modal > .options-modal`?

Comment: @xydope ну хочется посложнее что-нибудь попробовать, если есть такое)

Comment: @TopoR, но зачем усложнять?